# Least-Squares Property of Condtional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $Y$ be a vector-valued random element.
Then then for any $\sigma$-field the conditional expectation satisfies the *least-squares property*
$$
argmin_{X \in L^2(\mathscr{F})}( \mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2] )= \mathbb{E}[Y|\mathscr{F}].  
$$

My question is the following: if $g$ and $f$ are $\sigma(Y)$-measurable then what is the solution to the problem

$$
argmin_{X \in L^2(\mathscr{F})}( \mathbb{E}[(g(X)-f(Y))^2])?
$$

I expect something of the form $g(\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|\mathscr{F}])$ but I'm not certain, if and when that would be true.

Comment: Your original statement does not seem to be correct to me; the argmin of $E[(X-Y)^2]$ over $L^2(F)$ is the conditional expectation of $Y$. As for your second question, it will depend quite drastically on what $g$ is. $g$ might very well be nonconvex for example...

Comment: It's still wrong, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I missed the crucial exponent in my typo.  
Ultimately I only need $g\in C^2$ and if necessary (but I would prefer not) I may assume it is convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Partial Answer)*

If we make the added assumption that $g$ is injective and measurable wrt $\mathscr{F}$ then
$$
Z\triangleq f(Y)
$$
then the least squares problem
\begin{align}
\hat{X}\triangleq \min_{X \in L^2(\mathscr{F})} \mathbb{E}[(X-Z)^2] & = \mathbb{E}[Z|\mathscr{F}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[f(Y)|\mathscr{F}].
\end{align}

Now if $X$ in te minimization is of the form $g(\tilde{X})$ above then:
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathscr{F}] = \hat{X} = g(\tilde{X}),
$$
the left-invertibility of $g$ allow us to conclude that
$$
g^{-1}\left(\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathscr{F}] \right) = \tilde{X}
.
$$

*Note:*  If someone knows the solution dropping the assumption of injectiveness I would be happy to hear that solution also.